# How to create a simple Function in Remix.run

Tags: javascript, typescript, remix.run

I am new to Remix.run and Was stuck while i had to create a simple section navigator. which runs a JS script.

I wanted to pass a `section`'s `id` attribute as a parameter and scroll to that section when i click a certain button how can i do that?

```
function scrollTo(section:string){
    document.getElementById(section).scrollIntoView();//something like this but this line gives error
}
```

I am using typescript as a language for remix.run.

How can i include this here: So to use this as a *scroll to section* kind of button,

If there are any better approaches Please suggest.

```
import {
  Links,
  Meta,
  Outlet,
  Scripts,
} from "@remix-run/react";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <html>
      <head>
        <link
          rel="icon"
          href="data:image/x-icon;base64,AA"
        />
        <Meta />
        <Links />
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Hello world!</h1>
        <Outlet />

        <Scripts />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't show how you're using your `scrollTo` function. Also it would be helpful if you included the actual error you're getting.

With that said, you can use a standard `<a>` tag to scroll to *any* element with an `id` attribute. You just specify `href="#<id>"`

```html
<a href="#section-1">Scroll to Section 1</a>

<section id="section-1">
</section>
```